# Impossible to execute my firebase functions locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to run `firebase cloud functions` emulator in my local environment but I get a `EADDRINUSE` issue.

1. I can successfully run firebase emulator :

`✔  functions[main]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/firebaseapp/main).`

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! View status and logs at http://localhost:4000 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Other reserved ports: 4400, 4500

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
 
>  Server Started
>  Connected to MongoDB
```

2. However, after that things don't go as expected, when I use the link provided by the emulator :

`http://localhost:5001/firebaseapp/main`

to make my test request :

`http://localhost:5001/firebaseapp/main/test`

I get the following error :

```
>  events.js:288
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
>  
>  Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
>      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1309:16)
>      at listenInCluster (net.js:1357:12)
>      at Server.listen (net.js:1445:7)
>      at Function.listen (/Users/Desktop/fb_tour/functions/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
>      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/fb_tour/functions/index.js:61:5)
>      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
>      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:681:33
>      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
>      at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:5:58)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>  Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
>      at emitErrorNT (net.js:1336:8)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
>    code: 'EADDRINUSE',
>    errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
>    syscall: 'listen',
>    address: '::',
>    port: 5000
>  }
```

I tried to kill the port 5000 but apparently there is no active PID process so I couldn't get the PID. I also restarted my computer to force every process to shut down but this error still persist.

Any suggestion ?

EDIT : I got the same issue even when I change the listen port in my nodejs app. For e.g. when I set port 3000 I get the same error message telling that the port 3000 is already in use.

EDIT 2 : I think I have identified the cause of the issue. I have this warning message when I run the functions emulator

`It seems that you are running multiple instances of the emulator suite for project firebaseapp. This may result in unexpected behavior.`

I think there are two instances of my app running at the same time, causing this error. However I have no Idea about how to fix this.

Comment: If you have a bug report for the Firebase CLI that has a specific reproduction instructions, file a bug report on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: try killing processes on 5001 as well

Comment: I do this all the time, during development, incase of unhandled exception in code, they might throw error in the middle and I will kill 5001 after address already in use error

Comment: @vinoth10 As I said in my edit, I just found what causes this issue. I get this warning message `It seems that you are running multiple instances of the emulator suite for project firebaseapp. This may result in unexpected behavior.` and I don't know why multiple instances on my app are running at the same time.

Comment: I faced this before in writing cloud functions.
First of all you dont need to pass all these details to start admin app.
All I did was `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();` as first 2 lines in index.ts/index.js

then do

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const db = admin.firestore();

in respective cloud function

Comment: All these configs and initialization required only if you want to connect to another firebase project

Comment: If you logged in via terminal in your dev machine and deploy functions in that project, you dont need to explicitly create firebase app, just get it from admin. Server side apps are designed in such a way when using firebase

Answer (score 3):

if you have `app.listen()` in your function code then remove it and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the last update you provided, the error message was reported on [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2228#issuecomment-626693827) I think you can follow the suggestions there in order to avoid the issue.

It seems like you only need to CTRL-C command before to use the emulator. According to this [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2230), the issue has been solved.